# How can I see all the drives on my system, both mounted and unmounted?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, unix, mount

How can I see all the physical hard drives on my Ubuntu system — regardless of whether they're mounted — as well as their partition info, sizes, &c.? I have three physical drives, but only one seems to be mounted. I'd like to mount the other ones too, as I have some data on them.

Comment: What gets mounted is the filesystem on a partition, which might cover a whole disk, but I wouldn't call it `mounting a drive`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've used `fdisk -l` to solve this problem.

Comment: "fdisk -l | grep sd" should reduce some clutter if the drives are /dev/sdx etc

Answer (score 0):

You may also want to try the `cfdisk` command. I use it in conjunction with fdisk and I always find that it gives you a clearer view of my drives and partitions than fdisk.

Just be careful, though, because you can use it to break your partition table.